# Is it possible to programatically set the styles in a Vaadin 14 / Flow grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

For example I have a grid where I let the user define the colors for certain data using Vaadin 8 and I'd like to offer this in Vaadin 14 / Flow as well.

In Vaadin 8 I did (for each style/data type):

```
Page.getCurrent().getStyles()
    .add(".MyCustomTheme .v-grid-cell." + cssName + " { background-color:" + userSelectedColor + "; }");
```

then in the grid code I would do:

```
addColumn(myColumn).setStyleGenerator(cssName);
```

In Vaadin 14 / Flow I have:

```
addColumn(myColumn).setClassNameGenerator(cssName);
```

However I can't seem to figure out how to programmatically change the css values for cssName. In essence how do I do the first part where I inject my css in the Java code?

Just to add I couldn't do anything as shown here at: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/element-api/tutorial-dynamic-styling When I tried to do `grid.getElement().getStyle().set(...)` this would apply to the whole table rather than the rows.

Comment: Do you have a limited count of rows in your grid? If yes, I think it could be done with rowCount predefined CSS classes and CSS variables.

Comment: No row count limit.

Comment: @Hawk But let's say I had defined css classes how would I access them to change them? So for example let's say I had cssStyle1, cssStyle2, etc. how do I programatically change their values in a grid cell? In a component you get getElement().getStyle().set(...) but I can't figure out how to do this for rows in a grid...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use TemplateRenderer to inject styles, here is an example.

```
grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<Bean> of(
        "<div style$=\"[[item.styles]]\">[[item.data]]</div>")
        .withProperty("styles", "color: red")
        .withProperty("data", Bean::getData));
```

Also note, that Grid's table and its cells are in shadow DOM. So if you are using setClassNameGenerator, you need to set the styles in style module for Grid, instead of global css. I.e. set the generator

```
grid.addColumn(..).setClassNameGenerator(item -> item.getData() < 0 ? "red" : null);
```

Add the import for css

```
@CssImport(value = "my-grid-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-grid")
```

And in "frontend/my-grid-styles.css" use

```
.red {
   color: red;
}
```

Note, like explained in other answer, you can also set the color to be from css property.

```
.red {
   color: var(--my-grid-cell-color);
}
```

Then, you can just define the value of that color in Grid scope using (JavaScript call is not needed)

```
grid.getElement().getStyle().set("--my-grid-cell-color","red");
```

Comment: Is it possible to use an in-memory css provider instead of the `@CssImport(value = "my-grid-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-grid")` ? I'm kind of trying to achieve the same thing but without having to redeploy my app every time I want to add something to the CSS file, but instead programatically fetch new content for the CSS file from a backend.

Comment: In Vaadin 6 there used to be a class `org.vaadin.cssinject.CSSInject` that was used for such purposes. Is there anything similar to it in vaadin flow ?